# PHP_CodeSniffer Many Classes per file sniff

Tags: php, exception, phpcodesniffer

We have a standard in use, where we create exceptions within the main class for returning errors etc...  The problem is, that all the standard sniffs do not like this.  We are writing our own sniffs then for this, but thought I would inquire why this was not desirable?

For instance, we have:

```
<?php
class FOO_EXCEPTION extends Exception   {   }
class FOO_EXCEPTION_BAR extends FOO_EXCEPTION   {   }
class FOO_EXCEPTION_POLE extends FOO_EXCEPTION  {   }

class FOO
{
    public function MethodDoingSomething()
    {
        if('some condition happens')    {
            throw new FOO_EXCEPTION_BAR();
        }

        if('some other condition')  {
            throw new FOO_EXCEPTION_POLE();
        }
        ...
    }
}
?>
```

This allows our code to return different exceptions to indicate what happened to the caller, but if a dedicated try/catch is not available, the basic Exception may still be caught.

This comes in handy when working with databases or other external objects, since the nature of the error may be returned to a component higher up the call stack to handle the error.

For instance, if you are deleting a file, and the file does not exist, the code may throw the exception, but the caller has the option to ignore this if it was not concerned that the file did not exist, since it was trying to delete it anyhow.  However, another caller, could error out with the absence of a file that was suppose to exist when it was being deleted.

Comment: If you use an autoloader, then you don't need the Exception classes to be in the same file; each can sit in its own individual file, and needn't be loaded (using PHP memory) until it's actually referenced

Comment: True, but we keep them together for the logical reasons, that they are defined in the file and clearly visible for each developer to use, and to know what is available to be thrown.  Another issue is, as shown above, usually the exception is nothing more than a definition to be caught, so that creating it in an external file which could be loaded via an autoload seems a little over kill as well.

Comment: That's where a nice simple folder structure helps: You have the Foo class file in your classes folder; then a Foo folder under that where you have your Foo_Exception class file; and an Exception subfolder under that where you have the Foo_Exception_Bar and Foo_Exception_Pole class files.... equally logical, and it's easily read

Comment: I understand where you are going.  This would be quite straight forward, albeit a lot of directories and very short files.  My greatest concern is ensuring that all of our developers follow this and realize what exceptions are created.  I guess this format also works well for the Namespace structures for PHP 5.3.

Comment: It is a lot of directories and short files; but if you're using an autoloader and APC, that doesn't have any adverse affect on performance (on the contrary, it's typically a lot better because only what's actually needed is included into memory, and there's none of the overhead of loading the additional includes that aren't needed). The biggest issue with switching to a structure like this is the developer understanding of the structure; but it should be fairly intuitive

Comment: Could it possibly be something as simple as your use of `CONSTANT_CASE` rather than `ClassCase` for the name of a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, the coding standard which you describe in your question is perfectly reasonable. And I think for the purposes of your project it would be better to tweak the "standard multiple classes per file" sniff so that it works with your code **in this particular (special) case** rather than waste your time tweaking your codebase to comply with "the letter of the law" for this particular sniff.

I agree with the assertion that it is better *in general* to avoid putting multiple class definitions in a single file. But every argument I've read (so far) for moving **each and every** Exception-derived class into its own separate file strikes me as an exhortation to "improve" code by making it less readable. As a human, I gain no maintainability benefit from cluttering my code with files containing a single line, each.

It's true that it is easier to write an autoloader, for example, if each class lives in its own file. And if you're generating/compiling your PHP code from some sort of meta-language then it costs you nothing to add extra levels to your directory structure. But I reject the conclusion that this way of organizing the code actually improves it in any useful-to-humans way.

**EDIT:**
For the record, I **can** see that it would be a good idea to move the definition of an Exception-derived class into its own file **if** it actually contains some "testable" logic. In such cases you might need to mock/stub the class when writing automated tests for the logic which *uses* the class, which would require you to be able to load the class definition separately from the logic which uses it. But this **not** the situation described in the original question, where the Exception-derived classes are all "empty".

Comment: Thanks.  We use the Exceptions in the top for no other reason than simply having them to throw as it does appear clearer than all these small files which basically do nothing.  The main class has to be included to get the functionality, so it automatically brings the exceptions in as well, without the need to define autoloaders, etc...  We agree that it does not make the code any more maintainable, and internally, believe it makes it less so.  An external file may be forgotten about and not updated/referenced, etc...  With close to 1 million lines of code, no one can remember it all.

Comment: We're in a similar situation where I work (several million L.O.C. with tens of thousands of files), and are currently using a PHP coding standard for Exceptions which appears to be very similar to the one which you describe in your question.

Comment: Do you have a sniff for it currently?  I am looking to write one where it will look to ensure the multiple class has Exception in the name, not fool proof, but what I am trying.  I currently have written a sniff (needs to be modified for the exceptions) based on file name matching class name as well.

Comment: @StevenScott - I'm not currently using any sniffs to check for multiple classes in a single file, since we haven't (yet) decided to add any associated rules to our coding standard. But it would not be difficult to write one by implementing the PHP_CodeSniffer_Sniff interface - you can use the 'backet_opener' and 'bracket_closer' tokens for the T_OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET to check for an empty class body. One problem: recognizing classes which extend an Exception-derived class defined in *another file*. Either forbid this, or require Exception-derived classes to have names ending with 'Exception'.

Comment: Out classes for Exception already end in Exception (coding standard - but have to write a sniff for it), and then I am going to add a sniff to the class so an empty class that is an exception, has to be extended, and end in exception. Thanks for the help.